# DataFlow Query Not Replacing Variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a workable sql query

```
 ... where AcctPD >= '@{variables('StartDate')}'
```

and want to use a variable such as `StartDate` value of `202211`, a `varchar(6)`.

If I put `... where AcctPD >= '202211'` in the sql, the query works, and data is returned. But if I run the above for a variable substitution, I get

> at Source 'XXXXx': Parse error at line: 36, column: 41: Incorrect syntax near 'StartDate'.
> SQL Server error encountered while reading from the given table or
> while executing the given query.

Why?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ADF pipeline variables and pipeline parameters cannot be used directly in dataflow. In order to use the value of pipeline variable, a dataflow parameter is to be created and value of the pipeline variable should be passed to that dataflow parameter. I tried to repro this.
- Pipeline variable `StartDate` is created and value is assigned.

[image]

- Dataflow Query is run without using the variable. Data is read from the SQL table without any error.

[image: gif53]

- When variable is given in the Query, same error is produced.
  [image: gif51]
- In order to solve this, dataflow parameter named  `par_StartDate` is created.

[image]

- In Source transformation Query, open expression builder is selected.

[image]

- Query is written as `"select * from Target_merged_table where createdat='{$par_StartDate}'"` in dataflow expression builder.

[image]

[image]

- Sink transformation is added with csv file as a sink dataset.
- This dataflow is added in dataflow activity of pipeline. Value of pipeline variable `StartDate` is passed to dataflow parameter `par_StartDate`.
  [image: gif51]
- When pipeline is run, dataflow is executed successfully.

Comment: I'm missing something and getting "Data flow has parameters for which a value has not been provided, these values are necessary for data preview." I click on "see parameters" and I see my parameter and the need for an expression. Your example has a `select` in it which goes against a database, and not a pipeline variable. I don't have a `sink` dataset for csv ... is that a step needed?

Comment: Added `$par_StartDate` (which corresponds to the pipline variable) to my DataFlow `Parameter` parameter and I am geting data.

Comment: As mentioned, not understanding your example on the `DataFlow Expression builder`, for my situation and the sink. Could your answer be changed to focus it...or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm missing something and getting "Data flow has parameters for which a value has not been provided, these values are necessary for data preview." -- **I think you get this message when Data preview tab is clicked.** [image1](https://i.imgur.com/mseemBn.png) **Select click to see parameters. In Debug settings window, enter the sample value for the parameter.** [image2](https://i.imgur.com/9FcdCup.png) **Based on the value given, data will be displayed in data preview. Note: Value given in debug settings, will reflect only in data preview. This will not affect when pipeline is debugged.**

Comment: I don't have a `sink` dataset for csv ... is that a step needed? -- **No. Any sink dataset can be used. CSV dataset is used for this repro.**

Comment: As mentioned, not understanding your example on the DataFlow Expression builder-- **Edited answer; Added a step**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250385/discussion-between-aswin-and-megaman).